# Send email from web server by using AFNetworking

Tags: php, objective-c, smtp, sendmail, afnetworking

I've tried to send email without using MFMailComposeViewController, after some research i think AFNetowrking is the best way to do that but i cant to figure it out and make it work and I'm not really familiar with web programming.

Im using AFHTTPClient class, Here what i've done:

```
-(IBAction)sendMail
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://flameapp.net"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            txtName, @"si_contact_name1",
                            txtSubject, @"si_contact_subject1",
                            txtEmail, @"si_contact_email1",
                            txtMessage, @"si_contact_message1"
                            ,nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/?page_id=26" parameters:params];

    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://flameapp.net/?page_id=26"]];

    NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
    [client postPath:@"/?page_id=26" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", text);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Done. thank you woke me about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously re-consider not using MFMailComposeViewController—it's built-in, familiar, and works.

Of course, AFNetworking can't send e-mails directly. It looks like you're using AFNetworking to communicate with a server that takes parameters and then sends e-mails. It's up to you to hook up that POST request endpoint--everything with AFNetworking looks to be alright (although you generally don't append a query string for POST requests--that should probably just be another POST parameter)

Comment: He's sending from a web server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer me. I decided to do this by the apple built in HttpRequest. Work great. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what particular issues you were having, but it appears that inside the success block you are using your own (empty) `response` variable, rather than the `responseObject` that is automatically created for you.

i.e. If you did the following then you'd see at least what the server is returning:

```
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```